# Instapaper: automatically saving email newsletters

Tags: instapaper

Has anyone figured out a way to automatically save email newsletters (e.g Tech Crunch) to their Instapaper (read it later app)?

A "view in browser" link URL is common in newsletters, and I'm trying to figure out how to automatically grab these URLs and email them to my Instapaper email address.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use Google App Script + Chat GPT to instruct Gmail to extract the newsletter URL and send a new email to my Instapaper "article save" email address.